# trigger.io Run web error

Tags: node.js, trigger.io

When I run trigger.io web I get the following error . running it on windows xp machine. node.js is installed and correct path is given .

```
File "C:\Documents and Settings\Leadtech\forge-workspace\prachi\.template\generate_dynamic\module_dynamic\utils.py", line 338, in run_shell
    raise state.error
TypeError: environment can only contain strings
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a duplicate of this question:
[trigger.io Run web error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18330844/trigger-io-run-web-error)

A workaround is suggested there, and we'll consider a more permanent fix in the Trigger.io tooling soon.

Comment: where is the question with workaround ? can you please provide the link .

Answer (score 0):

There is a fix for this in Trigger.io platform version v2.0.2 - see https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/release_notes.html.